# How to get a coefficient matrix in Eigen?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

Ok so I want to do this operation in Eigen:

```
float StartMatrix[7][7] = { { 1, 4, 6, 9, 3, 5, 8 }, { 2, 5, 3, 7, 4, 8, 2 }, { 3, 6, 6, 7, 0, 2, 4 }, 
                            { 2, 4, 3, 7, 4, 8, 2 }, { 2, 3, 3, 11, 4, 8, 1 }, { 2, 12, 3, 7, 0, 8, 2 },
                            { 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 11, 2 } };

float TotalMatrix[7] = { 22, 15, 13, 26, 27, 33, 19 };

float CoMatrix[7][7] = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
        CoMatrix[row][col] = StartMatrix[row][col] / TotalMatrix[col];
    }

}
```

Divide each row by just the column in the TotalMatrix. And then I want to subtract the Identity matrix from the CoMatrix in Eigen and get the inverse on that (just to get an idea why I want to do this).

Problem is, how do I either perform this operation with Eigen, or somehow get the CoMatrix array into a matrix in Eigen so I can do stuff with it (like getting inverse etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code in Eigen would look something like this (after importing the Eigen namespace, `using namespace Eigen;`):

```
MatrixXd StartMatrix(7, 7);
StartMatrix << 
    1, 4, 6, 9, 3, 5, 8, 2, 5, 3, 7, 4, 8, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 0, 2, 4,
    2, 4, 3, 7, 4, 8, 2, 2, 3, 3, 11, 4, 8, 1, 2, 12, 3, 7, 0, 8, 2,
    2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 11, 2;

VectorXd TotalMatrix(7);
TotalMatrix << 22, 15, 13, 26, 27, 33, 19;

MatrixXd CoMatrix = MatrixXd::Zero(StartMatrix.rows(), StartMatrix.cols());

CoMatrix = StartMatrix.array() / (TotalMatrix.replicate(1,StartMatrix.cols())).array();
```

You can continue subtracting the identity matrix with

```
CoMatrix -= MatrixXd::Identity(CoMatrix.rows(), CoMatrix.cols());
```

or combine it with the previous expression as:

```
CoMatrix = (StartMatrix.array() / (TotalMatrix.replicate(1, StartMatrix.cols())).array()).matrix()
    - MatrixXd::Identity(CoMatrix.rows(), CoMatrix.cols());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated!